# How do i get Kotlin to run with Open JDK 16?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, kotlin

I wanted to create a simple Spring Boot projects using Intellij + the Kotlin language. I never thought i´d run into such huge problems... When i am trying to start the project i get following immediate error:

```
Kotlin: [Internal Error] java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.intellij.pom.java.LanguageLevel.<clinit>(LanguageLevel.java:25)
    at com.intellij.core.CoreLanguageLevelProjectExtension.<init>(CoreLanguageLevelProjectExtension.java:26)
    at com.intellij.core.JavaCoreProjectEnvironment.<init>(JavaCoreProjectEnvironment.java:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreProjectEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreProjectEnvironment.kt:26)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$ProjectEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:121)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.createForProduction(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:425)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.createCoreEnvironment(K2JVMCompiler.kt:226)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:152)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:52)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:88)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:98)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1500)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:691)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected void java.util.ResourceBundle.setParent(java.util.ResourceBundle) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @5d20b857
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:357)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
    at com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil.makeAccessible(ReflectionUtil.java:252)
    at com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil.getDeclaredMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:269)
    at com.intellij.DynamicBundle.<clinit>(DynamicBundle.java:22)
    ... 30 more
```

Of course i have read several threads about this issue... none of them helped so far. Some people said its a Maven issue, so i switched the default Intellij Maven version from 3.6 to the latest 3.8 release. That changed nothing...

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>net.drush</groupId>
    <artifactId>restdemo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>restdemo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>16</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.5.20</kotlin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                    </args>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                        <plugin>jpa</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-noarg</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Anybody any idea how to get Kotlin to work ?

Comment: Sorry for the missed typos.

Comment: Looks like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-47308 , try setting your kotlin-maven-plugin to ${kotlin.version} it was fixed in 1.5.0

Comment: It seems somehow that the kotlin version i describe inside the pom.xml is of no matter to the maven build since when i run this inside my intelliJ enviroment it uses the default kotlin plugin of intellij anyway. Im not sure why we even define this inside the pom.xml. I thought Maven figures everything out by itself and uses the according version that we state inside the file...

Comment: Maven doesn't guess which dependencies will need to use a property like ${kotlin.version} as their version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the kotlin-maven-plugin version to ${kotlin.version}.

It was a [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-43704) in 1.4.x, it is fixed in 1.5.x.